# Syntax Errors in VBA

Tags: vba, loops, if-statement, syntax

I keep getting errors (either else without if or loop without do) in this, and I really have no idea why... can anyone help?! Thanks!

```
Do Until (Range("I4").Value = 0)

    For i = 2 To lLastrow

                If Range("G" & i).Value = 0 Then
                    i = i + 1

                ElseIf Range("G" & i).Value < 0 Then
                      Do Until (Range("G" & i).Value = 0)
                      For j = 0 To i
                         If Range("F" & i - j).Value < 0 Then
                               Range("F" & i - j).Value = Range("F" & i - j).Value + 1
                              Else: j = j + 1
                              End If
                             Application.Calculate
                        Loop
                    ElseIf Range("G" & i).Value > 0 Then
                        Do Until (Range("G" & i).Value = 0)
                            For k = 0 To i
                             If Range("F" & i - k).Value > 0 Then
                              Range("F" & i - k).Value = Range("F" & i - k).Value - 1
                                   Else: k = k + 1
                                   End If
                               Application.Calculate
                        Loop
                End If


            Application.Calculate
Loop
```

Comment: You are missing `Next` for your `For` loops

Comment: This is why proper indentation matters.

Answer (score 4):

Try replacing the code below with what you have. You were missing `Next` for each of your `For` loops. `Do` and `Loop` go together, similarly `For` and `Next` go together (they form the basis for the loop).

Here's the code, I've cleaned this up as well to make it easier to follow.

```
Do Until (Range("I4").Value = 0)
    For i = 2 To lLastrow
        If Range("G" & i).Value = 0 Then
            i = i + 1
        ElseIf Range("G" & i).Value < 0 Then
            Do Until (Range("G" & i).Value = 0)
                For j = 0 To i
                    If Range("F" & i - j).Value < 0 Then
                        Range("F" & i - j).Value = Range("F" & i - j).Value + 1
                    Else
                        j = j + 1
                    End If
                    Application.Calculate
                Next j
            Loop
        ElseIf Range("G" & i).Value > 0 Then
            Do Until (Range("G" & i).Value = 0)
                For k = 0 To i
                    If Range("F" & i - k).Value > 0 Then
                        Range("F" & i - k).Value = Range("F" & i - k).Value - 1
                    Else
                        k = k + 1
                    End If
                    Application.Calculate
                Next k
            Loop
        End If
    Next i
    Application.Calculate
Loop
```

Comment: +1 for taking your time to cleanly indent the code. Furthermore to improve code control and debugging I'd always have every `Next` followed by its iterator variable as well (`Next j`, `Next k`, `Next i`). You may want to edit your code and take this inside, too

Comment: Added the Next suffix as you suggested

Comment: @user3598756 IMO adding the iterator variable to the `Next` statement is merely mild clutter - if you *need* them for readability, then your code is likely too nested (which, with 6 levels deep, is definitely the case here) and you should be refactoring (extract method) instead of  adding *more* visual noise.

Comment: @Mat's Mug agreed for seasoned developers, but for someone just learning the basics  (which it appears is maybe true with the OP) I think it's helpful to understand how they are related. Without the iterator, it makes the relationship harder to visualize. When I code, I don't add the iterator.

Comment: Thanks guys! Yes very much leaning the basics, thanks for the tips

Comment: @Mat'sMug: then we have different opinions about the iterator variable. While I agree with you about refactoring need in a too many nested loops scenario

Comment: @user3598756 indentation alone should make things pretty clear already. and if the loop body is too large to fit a single screen, again, the problem isn't the absence of the iterator variable in the `Next` statement. IMO that's like adding useless comments like `End If 'foo = 42` or `End Sub 'DoSomething` - it's useless noise, in any language. So yeah, let's agree to disagree.

Comment: @Mat'sMug, I never said that iterator variable is "the problem"

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `Next` statement for all you `For`loops

Try below code

```
Do Until (Range("I4").Value = 0)

    For i = 2 To lLastrow
      If Range("G" & i).Value = 0 Then
        i = i + 1
      ElseIf Range("G" & i).Value < 0 Then
        Do Until (Range("G" & i).Value = 0)
           For j = 0 To i
             If Range("F" & i - j).Value < 0 Then
                Range("F" & i - j).Value = Range("F" & i - j).Value + 1
             Else
                j = j + 1
             End If
             Application.Calculate
             Next'You missed this
         Loop
       ElseIf Range("G" & i).Value > 0 Then
          Do Until (Range("G" & i).Value = 0)
            For k = 0 To i
              If Range("F" & i - k).Value > 0 Then
                 Range("F" & i - k).Value = Range("F" & i - k).Value - 1
              Else
                k = k + 1
            End If
            Application.Calculate
            Next 'You missed this
          Loop
       End If

        Application.Calculate
    Next 'You missed this
Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

This is why *proper* and *consistent* indentation matters:

```
Do Until (Range("I4").Value = 0)
|   For i = 2 To lLastrow
|   |   If Range("G" & i).Value = 0 Then
|   |   |   i = i + 1
|   |   ElseIf Range("G" & i).Value < 0 Then
|   |   |   Do Until (Range("G" & i).Value = 0)
|   |   |   |   For j = 0 To i
|   |   |   |   |   If Range("F" & i - j).Value < 0 Then
|   |   |   |   |   |   Range("F" & i - j).Value = Range("F" & i - j).Value + 1
|   |   |   |   |   Else
|   |   |   |   |   |   j = j + 1
|   |   |   |   |   End If
|   |   |   |   |   Application.Calculate
|   |   |   |   Next '<<<<<<< MISSING!!
|   |   |   Loop
|   |   ElseIf Range("G" & i).Value > 0 Then
|   |   |   Do Until (Range("G" & i).Value = 0)
|   |   |   |   For k = 0 To i
|   |   |   |   |   If Range("F" & i - k).Value > 0 Then
|   |   |   |   |   |   Range("F" & i - k).Value = Range("F" & i - k).Value - 1
|   |   |   |   |   Else
|   |   |   |   |   |   k = k + 1
|   |   |   |   |   End If
|   |   |   |   |   Application.Calculate
|   |   |   |   Next '<<<<<<< MISSING!!
|   |   |   Loop
|   |   End If
|   |   Application.Calculate
|   Next '<<<<<<< MISSING!!
Loop
```

Now, you have 6 levels of nesting here, and quite much duplication. That's a sign you need to *refactor* and *extract a procedure* out of the inner nested code, to eliminate redundancies and improve the code's readability and maintainability (one modification *should* mean *one single place* to change the code).

If your code works as intended, I'd suggest you bring it (the whole procedure, or even the entire module!) over to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) for a cleanup and tips to improve and solidity your code (e.g. you probably don't need to `Calculate` as often as you do, and unqualified `Range` calls implicitly refer to the active worksheet - and this might cause unexpected bugs later!).

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I'll head over there now! Very much leaning the basics, so its very untidy I know, sorry!

Comment: @AlexW if you stick around and regularly put your working code up for review on [codereview.se], you'll quickly learn how to write clean, maintainable code. See you on the other side!

Comment: I do hope so! Ill keep practicing